# I am unable to install ubuntu 18.04 on my virtualbox 6.1 continues to freeze during install

Tags: virtualization

I am using windows 10 (1809) host. My error indicates the problem is with the partitioning during the install. I'm not sure why the guest install will not allow installation.

Thanks

Huston

Comment: have you created the virtual disk for this virtual machine?

Comment: Did you [verify your .iso download](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu)? Corrupted or incomplete .iso downloads are a common source of mysterious install failures..